# Why is the database failing to initialise in my .NET Web Application project, when I attempt to access data via another project in my solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, console-application

I have **one** solution (.NET framework).

In that solution I have a *console application* and a *web application* (C#).

The *console application* uses code first entity framework. As such, it contains the data models, their context, and all the migration folders, etc.

I am using **(localDb)/MSSQLLocalDB** as my server name and **I can access data successfully** in the console application.

The *web application* references the console application. Here, I have my views, controllers, and general content folders.

When I want to access data from the 'Item' table, say for instance in the 'Home' controller, I could use:

```
ItemContext itemTable = new ItemContext();
var firstItem = itemTable.Item.Find(0);
```

There appear to be no errors, the project builds successfully.

**However**, an exception occurs whenever I run the web application project.

```
System.Data.DataException: 'An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.'
2 Inner Exceptions:
- EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
- SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Source\TrailBlazer\TrailBlazer.Web\App_Data\TrailBlazer.Context.ItemContext.mdf' as database 'TrailBlazer.Context.ItemContext'.
```

Ultimately, I am trying to avoid creating models or database related entities twice. I want to use the models in the console application.

It appears to be attempting to attach an '.mdf' file from the web application, as the database... I am not sure what that means.

What do I need to do to make this work?

---

When I **debug** the web application and step into '*itemTable.Item.Find(0);*', that takes my to my console application migration *Configuration.cs* file and steps through the Configuration() method.

```
   namespace SolutionName.Migrations
   {
        using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
        
        internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SolutionName.Context.ItemContext>
        {
            public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the exception occurs immediately **after** returning to the controller.

Could this be something to do with my migrations configuration?

Comment: Without forensically inspecting everything you have done, Have you verified that the file is available to your application and has the appropriate permissions?

Comment: I have the correct access modifiers on my classes if that's what you mean... Otherwise, I have not changed the permissions for any files. Which file are you are referring to?